# marquee gets restarted once it reached to left pane

Tags: html, angular, firefox, ecmascript-6, mozilla

in my angular 6 code i am writing marquee which renders a array of objects which works absolutely fine in chrome.

but when ran same code in firefox mozilla it got restared once it reached to left pane.

i have tried the following and serached a lot used scroll, behavior, loop properties also but didnt worked

```
<marquee *ngIf="tickerChangeFlag" onmousehover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let i of arrToBind"> i.scripDescription </li>
    </ul>  
</marquee>
```

Comment: the marquee element is not deprecated, it's obsolete. It may work in some browsers but not in everyone. see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: Exactly. given code works fine in chrome but not in mozilla i tried all ways around but didnt found any working solution

Comment: Me too have same problem ?did you solve issue before ?
    });